# Strings with varying lengths and number sequence in R

Tags: r, string

I have a column that looks like this:

| SNO | Label |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | #Name-account-dynamic-table-301889874517022 |
| 2 | #Name-account-dynamic-table-301892680435489 |
| 3 | #Name-account-dynamic-table-301898303041520 |
| 4 | #Name-account-dynamic-table-301899707194367 |
| 5 | #PartyName-_oj131-300010926780895 |
| 6 | #PartyName-_oj145-100049488429695 |
| 7 | #PartyName-_oj148-100046909736911 |
| 8 | #PartyName-_oj156-100039245551420 |
| 9 | #SalesCreditImage_100005748173584 |
| 10 | #SalesCreditImage_1676885837179 |
| 11 | #SalesCreditImage_1676894490983 |
| 12 | #SalesCreditImage_1677180209183 |
| 13 | #SalesCreditImage_1677221857743 |
| 14 | #SalesCreditImage_300007572814764 |
| 15 | #SalesCreditImage_300010430355109 |
| 16 | #_oj1046_headerContainer |
| 17 | #_oj1053_headerContainer |
| 18 | #_oj110_h |

I am trying to categorize these rows. The first four rows belong to one category. From 5 - 8, the second category; 9 - 15, third category, 16 - 17 fourth category, and 18 is standalone.

Because the strings are of varying lengths, I am finding it difficult to categorize these items. The character part of the string is the same, only the number part varies.

Can someone here help me categorize these items?

Comment: What do you mean by "categorize" - create a new column containing an integer that refers to the category?

Comment: Yes, create a new column with any identifying label.

Comment: What is the *logic* behind the categories? The current answer by Andre uses an (IMHO) good guess, but it is only a *guess*. You are the only one here who knows what the actual rules are.

Answer (score 0):

One approach using `gsub` to modify the strings. Since 16-18 have rather opposite requirements a solution is to split the process in two parts.

```
df$category <- gsub("_|.*\\d+", "", df$Label)

df$category <- paste0(gsub("#|_|-.*|\\d+.*", "", df$Label), df$category)

df
   SNO                                       Label          category
1    1 #Name-account-dynamic-table-301889874517022              Name
2    2 #Name-account-dynamic-table-301892680435489              Name
3    3 #Name-account-dynamic-table-301898303041520              Name
4    4 #Name-account-dynamic-table-301899707194367              Name
5    5           #PartyName-_oj131-300010926780895         PartyName
6    6           #PartyName-_oj145-100049488429695         PartyName
7    7           #PartyName-_oj148-100046909736911         PartyName
8    8           #PartyName-_oj156-100039245551420         PartyName
9    9           #SalesCreditImage_100005748173584  SalesCreditImage
10  10             #SalesCreditImage_1676885837179  SalesCreditImage
11  11             #SalesCreditImage_1676894490983  SalesCreditImage
12  12             #SalesCreditImage_1677180209183  SalesCreditImage
13  13             #SalesCreditImage_1677221857743  SalesCreditImage
14  14           #SalesCreditImage_300007572814764  SalesCreditImage
15  15           #SalesCreditImage_300010430355109  SalesCreditImage
16  16                    #_oj1046_headerContainer ojheaderContainer
17  17                    #_oj1053_headerContainer ojheaderContainer
18  18                                   #_oj110_h               ojh
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(SNO = 1:18, Label = c("#Name-account-dynamic-table-301889874517022", 
"#Name-account-dynamic-table-301892680435489", "#Name-account-dynamic-table-301898303041520", 
"#Name-account-dynamic-table-301899707194367", "#PartyName-_oj131-300010926780895", 
"#PartyName-_oj145-100049488429695", "#PartyName-_oj148-100046909736911", 
"#PartyName-_oj156-100039245551420", "#SalesCreditImage_100005748173584", 
"#SalesCreditImage_1676885837179", "#SalesCreditImage_1676894490983", 
"#SalesCreditImage_1677180209183", "#SalesCreditImage_1677221857743", 
"#SalesCreditImage_300007572814764", "#SalesCreditImage_300010430355109", 
"#_oj1046_headerContainer", "#_oj1053_headerContainer", "#_oj110_h"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly the rule is to distinguish between the last row and the two preceding ones, so either you could just hard-code the category or assign a consecutive ID based on the part of the `Label` that remains after removing digits, underscores etc.:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# hard-code new column containing category
df |> 
  mutate(category = case_match(
    row_number(),
    1:4 ~ 1,
    5:8 ~ 2,
    9:15 ~ 3,
    16:17 ~ 4,
    18 ~ 5
  ))
#> # A tibble: 18 × 3
#>    SNO   Label                                       category
#>    <chr> <chr>                                          <dbl>
#>  1 1     #Name-account-dynamic-table-301889874517022        1
#>  2 2     #Name-account-dynamic-table-301892680435489        1
#>  3 3     #Name-account-dynamic-table-301898303041520        1
#>  4 4     #Name-account-dynamic-table-301899707194367        1
#>  5 5     #PartyName-_oj131-300010926780895                  2
#>  6 6     #PartyName-_oj145-100049488429695                  2
#>  7 7     #PartyName-_oj148-100046909736911                  2
#>  8 8     #PartyName-_oj156-100039245551420                  2
#>  9 9     #SalesCreditImage_100005748173584                  3
#> 10 10    #SalesCreditImage_1676885837179                    3
#> 11 11    #SalesCreditImage_1676894490983                    3
#> 12 12    #SalesCreditImage_1677180209183                    3
#> 13 13    #SalesCreditImage_1677221857743                    3
#> 14 14    #SalesCreditImage_300007572814764                  3
#> 15 15    #SalesCreditImage_300010430355109                  3
#> 16 16    #_oj1046_headerContainer                           4
#> 17 17    #_oj1053_headerContainer                           4
#> 18 18    #_oj110_h                                          5
```

or

```r
# create continuous ID that increments when string part changes
df |> 
  mutate(category_label = str_remove_all(Label, "[#_\\-\\d]"),
         category_id = consecutive_id(category_label))
#> # A tibble: 18 × 4
#>    SNO   Label                                       category_label  category_id
#>    <chr> <chr>                                       <chr>                 <int>
#>  1 1     #Name-account-dynamic-table-301889874517022 Nameaccountdyn…           1
#>  2 2     #Name-account-dynamic-table-301892680435489 Nameaccountdyn…           1
#>  3 3     #Name-account-dynamic-table-301898303041520 Nameaccountdyn…           1
#>  4 4     #Name-account-dynamic-table-301899707194367 Nameaccountdyn…           1
#>  5 5     #PartyName-_oj131-300010926780895           PartyNameoj               2
#>  6 6     #PartyName-_oj145-100049488429695           PartyNameoj               2
#>  7 7     #PartyName-_oj148-100046909736911           PartyNameoj               2
#>  8 8     #PartyName-_oj156-100039245551420           PartyNameoj               2
#>  9 9     #SalesCreditImage_100005748173584           SalesCreditIma…           3
#> 10 10    #SalesCreditImage_1676885837179             SalesCreditIma…           3
#> 11 11    #SalesCreditImage_1676894490983             SalesCreditIma…           3
#> 12 12    #SalesCreditImage_1677180209183             SalesCreditIma…           3
#> 13 13    #SalesCreditImage_1677221857743             SalesCreditIma…           3
#> 14 14    #SalesCreditImage_300007572814764           SalesCreditIma…           3
#> 15 15    #SalesCreditImage_300010430355109           SalesCreditIma…           3
#> 16 16    #_oj1046_headerContainer                    ojheaderContai…           4
#> 17 17    #_oj1053_headerContainer                    ojheaderContai…           4
#> 18 18    #_oj110_h                                   ojh                       5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

where

```r
df <- tribble(
  ~SNO, ~Label,
  "1",  "#Name-account-dynamic-table-301889874517022",
  "2",  "#Name-account-dynamic-table-301892680435489",
  "3",  "#Name-account-dynamic-table-301898303041520",
  "4",  "#Name-account-dynamic-table-301899707194367",
  "5",  "#PartyName-_oj131-300010926780895",
  "6",  "#PartyName-_oj145-100049488429695",
  "7",  "#PartyName-_oj148-100046909736911",
  "8",  "#PartyName-_oj156-100039245551420",
  "9",  "#SalesCreditImage_100005748173584",
  "10", "#SalesCreditImage_1676885837179",
  "11", "#SalesCreditImage_1676894490983",
  "12", "#SalesCreditImage_1677180209183",
  "13", "#SalesCreditImage_1677221857743",
  "14", "#SalesCreditImage_300007572814764",
  "15", "#SalesCreditImage_300010430355109",
  "16", "#_oj1046_headerContainer",
  "17", "#_oj1053_headerContainer",
  "18", "#_oj110_h"
)
```